# Problem with first program in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am having some problems in executing my first socket.io program. Here is the code

```
var io=require('socket.io');
var http=require('http');

server =http.createServer(function(req,res) {
res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/html'});
res.write('welcome');
res.end();
});

server.listen(7777);

var socket = io.listen(server);

socket.on('connection', function (client) {
  console.log('client connected');

  client.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });

  client.on('another', function (data) {
  console.log(data);
  });

});
```

And here is my client side code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:7777/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:7777");
socket.on('news',function(data) {
alert(data);
socket.emit('another',{my:'data'});
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

EDIT: Now, i get an error in my server terminal "info - client protocol unsupported"

what am i doing wrong here? Thanks

Comment: Are you using an ancient browser? Try chrome/firefox4+

Comment: I am using firefox 5 on ubuntu

Comment: There were BIG changes in Socket.IO 0.7.  Your code is written for Socket.IO <= 0.6.  What version of Socket.IO are you running?

Comment: Someone please help. I keep getting this error

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import a javascript file from the socket io port instead of the web server port.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:7777/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js"> </script>
```

You need to give the correct src parameter.  For newer version of socket io, this would be something like socket/socket.io.js.